# How to host React App and Dot Net core webAPI with SignalR in AWS and Docker environment

Tags: .net-core, react-redux, signalr

I have React application as front end and Dot net core WebApi as back end. We are using SignalR for real time communication. We deployed front end application in AWS S3 bucket and back end in Docker.

SignalR communication is working fine in local environment. But when we deploy into docker broadcasting is sometimes working sometimes not.

Do we need Redis backplane or we can use AWS cloud front to work with this?

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest to use WebSockets instead of SignalR, since signalR works on long polling mechanism which makes more resources consumption which will lead to increase in billing cost.